# Go Online in TFS without check-out unmodified files

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

Due to bad network connection my solution gone offline in TFS, Now it is asking 'Go Online' to connect to TFS. But I afraid that when I go online by selecting solution level all files would we be checked-out, than I won't be able to find out which files really has modifications.

How can I 'go online' by checking-out those files only, which really has been modified

Below screenshot by default checking all files

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ae7a335-6abb-4214-9376-6ea7c061d4a5/go-online-from-offline-solution?forum=tfsgeneral) thread you have two options:

1. If you are sure that there are no pending changes in the other files that have been checked out, then nothing to sweat about, files that don't have changes will not be checked in, you will get a comment pop up saying the file has no pending changes to check in.
2. If you know the files that you need, then select those file and Shelve as pending changes. Shelve will preserve those changes on the server. Undo the rest of the checked out files in the solutions. Perform a get latest and do unshelve to bring the changes in those selected files back.

Comment: Literally I have idea how many files I have modified. In my solution 10 projects are there, I was working across solution.